# Deploying PrimeFaces application on Websphere

Tags: jsf, websphere, cdi

I've been trying to deploy PrimeFaces application which I have been developing for some time on WebSphere app server but am getting this error. I've posted question on PF forum but they have said it has nothing to do with PF. Also have posted it on websphere forum but haven't gotten much there except that it has something to do with CDI as @Kukeltje said.

```
9/27/19 13:08:53:476 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:477 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/META-INF/application.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:477 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/cus/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/cver/BASE/controlOpDefs.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:478 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/deployment.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:478 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.12.jar/META-INF/web-fragment.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:479 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/ibm-managed-beans.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:479 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/META-INF/ibm-application-bnd.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:480 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/ibm-metadata.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:480 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/web_merged.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:481 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar/META-INF/web-fragment.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:481 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:482 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/cus/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/cver/BASE/cu-ref.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:482 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/ibm-web-ext.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:483 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/cus/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/cver/BASE/cu.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:484 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/META-INF/ibm-application-runtime.props.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:484 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/META-INF/was.policy.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:485 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/blas/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/bver/BASE/bla.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:486 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/ibm-managed-bean-bnd.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:486 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/META-INF/was.webmodule.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:487 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:488 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/META-INF/was.module.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:489 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/ibm-managed-beans_merged.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:489 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar/META-INF/web-fragment.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:490 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0015I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin created document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/applications/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.ear/deployments/OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war/OOT-1.0.0 - OOT.war/WEB-INF/ibm-web-bnd.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:53:491 CEST] 000001a9 FileRepositor A   ADMR0016I: User defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin modified document cells/wastest11Node01Cell/nodes/wastest11Node01/serverindex.xml.
[9/27/19 13:08:58:241 CEST] 00000130 AdminHelper   A   ADMN1008I: An attempt is made to start the OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war application. (User ID = defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/wasadmin)
[9/27/19 13:08:58:248 CEST] 00000130 CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit WebSphere:cuname=OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war.
[9/27/19 13:08:58:293 CEST] 00000130 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I: Starting application: OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war
[9/27/19 13:08:58:293 CEST] 00000130 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0203I: Application: OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war  Application build level: 1.0.0 - OOT
[9/27/19 13:09:03:545 CEST] 00000130 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.JspAuthorizeTag class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionHandler
[9/27/19 13:09:03:558 CEST] 00000130 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.security.taglibs.csrf.CsrfInputTag class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken
[9/27/19 13:09:03:567 CEST] 00000130 MethodMap     W   CWNEN0049W: Resource annotations on the methods of the org.springframework.security.taglibs.csrf.CsrfMetaTagsTag class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken
[9/27/19 13:09:03:572 CEST] 00000130 InjectionProc W   CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the org.springframework.security.taglibs.authz.AccessControlListTag class will be ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator
[9/27/19 13:09:03:658 CEST] 00000130 Event         Z org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl checkRequiredTypeAnnotations WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.omnifaces.VetoAnnotatedTypeExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<T>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
[9/27/19 13:09:04:102 CEST] 00000130 ApplicationMg E   WSVR0101W: An error occurred starting, OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war
[9/27/19 13:09:04:103 CEST] 00000130 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0217I: Stopping application: OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war
[9/27/19 13:09:04:112 CEST] 00000130 RuntimeFactor W   Application is already stopped [ OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war ]
[9/27/19 13:09:04:116 CEST] 00000130 ApplicationMg A   WSVR0220I: Application stopped: OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war
[9/27/19 13:09:04:122 CEST] 00000130 CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war in BLA WebSphere:blaname=OOT-1_0_0 - OOT_war failed to start.
[9/27/19 13:09:04:123 CEST] 00000130 MBeanHelper   E   Could not invoke an operation on object: WebSphere:name=ApplicationManager,process=server1,platform=proxy,node=wastest11Node01,version=9.0.5.0,type=ApplicationManager,mbeanIdentifier=ApplicationManager,cell=wastest11Node01Cell,spec=1.0 because of an mbean exception: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIRuntimeException: com.ibm.ws.cdi.CDIDeploymentRuntimeException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1847)
       at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:703)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
       at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:96)
```

Has anyone encountered this error and if so how do we fix it? Application is built with PF 7.0 with maven and spring boot and trying to deploy it on WAS 9.0 server.

EDIT: After requesting stacktrace from my colleague this is what he has sent me: https://justpaste.it/2stnb (had to do it this way because its too big)

Comment: There is nothing PrimeFaces related in the question (so the PF forum is right!) just a jsf (faces) thing realated to CDI, so you better remove the PrimeFaces tag (and java tag for that matter since it is too generic) and add 'cdi' and 'jsf' to there. And are you sure there is not more in the stacktrace? Oh and the application is already stopping before this error!!!

Comment: And the 'title' too ;-) And maybe even the 'intro'

Comment: @Kukeltje I've cut the top part of the stack trace, but will edit the question so that it is seen

Comment: Root causes are ALWAYS at the bottom of the stacktrace. And did you do "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=websphere++com.sun.faces.cdi.CdiUtils.%3Cclinit%3E%28CdiUtils.java%3A84%29" ? You did not mention anything about searching (and keep track) like requested in [ask]

Comment: @Kukeltje look who or whatever you are I'm here just asking for help and ofcourse I've googled it why would i come here in the first place if google doesnt know it, I know my question isn't asked in the best possible way but I'm just looking for help since I've got no one to ask

Comment: Then why if I google I get lots of info you can try (and should have tried). That part is not for us to do. I did not downvote but please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  What I am doing IS trying to help. It is just not doing al the searching for you (I can stop commenting if you like, no problem. Lots of other things I can do). And you did not post more of the STACKTRACE, you posted more of the LOGGING before the stacktrace, you effectively even posted less of the stacktrace. If you want help, you need to get the question well formulated and having the right content.

Comment: @Kukeltje I apologize for my previous comment and would like to thank you for helpful advices. Ill look into stacktrace and will edit the question here, also will do some research to make the question as best as possible. Once again thanks :)

Comment: No problem, lets see if we can get to the root of this problem.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.security.....` looks like some spring security libraries are missing. Check if spring security related jars are in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Is your app actually using CDI?  It looks like the app is using Mojarra instead of the server provided JSF implementation - it is a known limitation that third-party JSF providers do not work well with CDI on WAS.

Comment: To go from beginning, I'm new to whole jsf world (primefaces is framework that im working with) and I've been doing those "hello world" examples that google threw at me. After some time I've been asigned to develop a application so I basicly just did a "hello world" example that is using spring boot and maven and from that started creating the application. So to answer your questions, no its not using CDI and for @BalusC a lot of things are unclear to me and im trying to dig myself from a whole of not knowing anything to understanding some things...